# Add dropdown list in tablesorter.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want filter and sort option in html table. I tried 'tablesorter.js',

I can sort the table fields by using this module. But I can't add drop down list and filter box with table fields.

Anybody can help me??

Comment: Show Your Code !! Where it gets problem ?

Comment: please tell me how to add dropdown list and filterbox in tablesorter.js http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo now my application works like this

Comment: I want to add dropdown list and filter box with the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using  [This.](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo)

This is HTML table shorter.

**OR**

[(**DEMO**)](http://jsfiddle.net/Yke6M/36/)  for short using drop-down list

```
$('table').tablesorter();

$('select').change(function(){
    var column = parseInt($(this).val(), 10),
        direction = 1, // 0 = descending, 1 = ascending
        sort = [[ column, direction ]];
    if (column >= 0) {
        $('table').trigger("sorton", [sort]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it. I want to add dropdown list and filter box with the fields.

Comment: You know any other modules for doing the same??

Comment: You know how to add the dropdown list in a particular field only. For example add dropdown list only to 'Alphabetic' field??

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/viralshah/Yke6M/38/ Else to short click on other columns and you ll have sorting

Comment: I want dropdown list on table header field. when we click on this dropdown all values in this field will list(no duplicate values). when we select one value from the list, corresponding rows will disply on table. I need this functionality. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a drop down list filter to the table column by adding a class="filter-select" to the  for that column in the .

```
<thead><th>Col 1></th><th class="filter-select">Col2</th></thead>
```

Or you can add a filter function for that column:

```
filter_functions : {

    // Add select menu to 3rd column (column numbers are zero-based).
    // Set the column value to true, and/or add "filter-select" class name to header
    2 : true,
}
```